# Can Entity Framework Core 7 include navigational properties that have the "internal" access modifier

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, domain-driven-design

I have a model that looks something like this

```
public sealed class Foo : EntityBase, IAggregateRoot
{
    internal ICollection<Bar> Bars  { get; init; } = new List<Bar>();

    public void AddBars(SomeDto someDto)
    {
        Bars.Add(new(){SomeProperty = someDto.SomeProperty}
    }
}

internal sealed class Bar : EntityBase
{
    internal required string SomeProperty { get; init; }
}
```

Both these classes exist in my domain layer model project. I am trying to do domain-driven design here.

In my application services layer project, I want to reference the domain project but I only want to be able to new up a `Foo` and not a `Bar`.

In my infrastructure project I have wired up EF Core 7 using Fluent API.

Since `Bar` is internal, I am finding it hard to map this navigational property to a table.

I don't want to expose internals in the infrastructure project.

Should I just make `Bar` public but not add it to the `DbSet`. That way people can only new up a `Bar` but not go something like

```
dbset.Add<Bar>(new Bar())
```

Ideally the `Bar` class is hidden from all other projects. And only my aggregate root `Foo` can modify this.

Didn't find much information in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Comment: *Since Bar is internal, I am finding it hard to map this navigational property to a table.* Only if it's in another assembly than EF.

Comment: I don't know specifically for internal properties, but I personally use a DDD approach when working with entities, though with public getters, internal setters, and public action methods that manipulate state through the setters.  In my case the objective is that an entity should always represent valid state so certain actions might involve updating several properties, so having an action method ensures these are all provided/computed/validated and updated together than the possibility of having invalid combinations persisted.

Comment: Also, if you want Bars to belong to Foo and not have/promote someone using a Bars DbSet, then EFCore introduced "Owned" entity relationships which from the DB side are just standard 1-to-many or 1-to-one relationships, but EF restricts their use so an owned entity is only ever accessed though it's owner.